# Android: Can i put some image (Logo etc.) in <item></item> tag together with title

Tags: android, android-menu

I have xml layout in values/menu_items.xml for menu items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<string-array name="menu_items">
    <item ></item>
    <item ></item>
    <item ></item>
    <item ></item>
</string-array>
```

I populate these items from my database with following code from MainActivity.java class:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mLayout = (MainLayout) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.activity_main, null);
    setContentView(mLayout);


    //opens database
    datasource = new CommentsDataSource(this);
    datasource.open();



    //menu_items list
    lvMenuItems =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_items);

    ArrayList<Category> meniVrednosti;
    meniVrednosti = new ArrayList<Category>();

//returns number of requested elements:
    int i= datasource.vratiBrojElemenataSaZadatimId(0);


    //for loop to populate menu_items.xml between tags <item></item>:
    for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        lvMenuItems[j] = (datasource.getCategoryViaParentIDandID(0, 
                10+j).toString()).replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]","");

    }
...
```

**So, my question is** ***how i can put images*** (picture, logo etc..) ***together with that names*** from **database**. For **Example**:

- (This is where picture goes) (this is MenuItemNO1, text between tags are from database)
- (This is where picture goes) MenuItemNO2
- (This is where picture goes) MenuItemNO3

I tried so many ways to do it, but i couldn't. Nothing worked for me far by now.
I hope so that you can help me.
Tell me if u need more info. Thanks in advance. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only put data that can be represented as a `String` in a string-array element.  However, if you have severals pieces of data you want in each item and they can all be represented as a `String`, you can then separate them with a delimiter.  Generally I use the pipe symbol `|` then you can get the array out of the resources, iterate through them and split on your delimiter to get the separate data again.

#### Updated with example:

Assuming some XML like this:

```
<string-array name="menu_items">
    <item>/path/to/images/image1.png|First Image</item>
    <item>/path/to/images/image2.png|Second Image</item>
    <item>/path/to/images/image3.png|Third Image</item>
    <item>/path/to/images/image4.png|Fourth Image</item>
</string-array>
```

You could parse it to get the image and title out like this:

```
private Map<String, String> parseImageArray {
    Map<String, String> imageMap = new Map<String, String>();
    String[] imageArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_items);

    for (String arrayEntry : imageArray) {
        String[] keyValue = arrayEntry.split("|");
        imageMap.put(keyValue[1], keyValue[0]);
    }

    return imageMap;
}
```

Now you have a Map of the image title to image paths

Comment: I wanna to put image path and title from database inside it. Can u provide some example of code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can put strings only in the item-elments. You can put in the path of your images, name or the size or whatever as a string but you can't put any other objects as far as I know and as the name "string-array" may suggest :).
I suppose, what you need is a custom menu, so you can style the menu items as you wish.

Check this link to get an introduction http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html .
Search for some custom menu on android tutorials on the internet. Right now I can't recommend you any, sorry. But maybe someone else can give you the right direction.
BTW What menu do you like to create - options menu?

Comment: Its main menu.. When i click on item in it, fragments get created, and sliding menu appears from right to the left, that slide contains sub-category.. something similiar to youtube app for android.. Thanks for answer, i will keep searching.. btw, i guess i tried already with image path, and i got image path name in my menu, above the item name.. i should used listview for that, but now is damage done, i can't rework my code for that.. It must be a way that i can pust image standing to menu item.. Maybe i can put every single <item></item> i group and add picture for it. maybe it will work. :)